# Error in doc_parse_file using rvest to scrape multiple pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the links from multiple pages of a web forum, and I'm getting an error message that I'm not sure how to fix.

I tried the following, using rvest and purrr

```
pages <- c("https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page") %>%
  paste0(1:18000) %>%
  paste0(c(".html"))

i<-1
pages.subset<-pages[1:(i+49)==(i+49)]
pages.subset<-as_data_frame(pages.subset)

scrape_links<-function(pages.subset){read_html(pages.subset) %>% html_node(".topictitle") %>% html_attr('href')}
links<-map_df(pages.subset, scrape_links)
```

However, I got this error message

Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=360].

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not 100% sure what caused the error, it seems that passing an entire data.frame as list in the `map_df` command blew things up. I have readjusted you code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

pages <- c("https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page") %>%
  paste0(1:18000) %>%
  paste0(c(".html"))

scrape_links <- function(url) {
  out <- url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_node(".topictitle") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  return(out)
}

links <- tibble(page = pages[1:(50) == (50)]) %>%
  mutate(url = map_chr(page, scrape_links))

head(links)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   page                                                                  url                                                                                                            
#   <chr>                                                                 <chr>                                                                                                          
# 1 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page50.html  https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
# 2 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page100.html https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
# 3 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page150.html https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
# 4 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page200.html https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
# 5 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page250.html https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
# 6 https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/page300.html https://www.immigrationboards.com/eea-route-applications/covid-19-home-office-immigration-guidance-t299291.html
```